# SQL SERVER Restore Problems

Tags: sql

I have created a backup of my production database and whenever I try to restore it on my local machine I get the following error:

The media family on device C:\projects.......name_of_the_database_.bak is incorrectly formed. SQL SERVER cannot process this media family. RESTORE HEADERONLY is terminating abnormally.

Comment: How are you transferring the backup file to your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this when trying to restore from portable media.  Try copying the file to your machine first then restoring.

Comment: I used the export data option as the restore was not working correctly.